# Accessing child class members using pointer to a base abstact class, which can't be dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have a player class, with:

```
typedef string cptype;
map <cptype, unique_ptr<Cp> > Cps;
```

I have added a pointer to this map with:

```
Cps.insert(make_pair("Pos", unique_ptr<Cp>(new PosCp())));
```

Now When I try to access the pos member variable of PosCp using this:

```
Cps["Pos"]->pos = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
```

I get the error:

```
class Cp has no member pos
```

When I try using `dynamic_cast`, with the following:

```
dynamic_cast<PosCp*>(Cps["Pos"])->pos = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
```

I get the error:

```
cannot dynamic_cast [this object]
```

(And rightfully so, I don't want to change the pointer, I just want to access the member variable)

How can I access member `pos` without changing the type of pointer in the map?

Here are the `Cp` and `PosCp` classes:

```
class Cp
{
    public:
        Cp();
        virtual ~Cp();

        cptype type;
};
```

---

```
class PosCp : public Cp
{
    public:
        PosCp();
        ~PosCp();

        sf::Vector2f pos;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
if (PosCp * p = dynamic_cast<PosCp *>(Cps["Pos"].get()))
{
    p->pos = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
}
else
{
    // most-derived type of *Cps["Pos"] is not PosCp
}
```

Comment: More importantly, what is the importance of the if here? what happens if the predicate fails?

Comment: *shudder* assignments within if statements :(

Comment: @Yaxlat Then it doesn't point to a PosCp. What happens is up to you.

Comment: @paulm: Nothing is assigned here.

Comment: "if (PosCp * p = " can you explain how this isn't an assignment?

Comment: @paulm: Is `int a = 10;` an assignment? (Hint: no.)

Comment: @paulm also note that the standard committee think it's useful enough to extend to types that aren't contextually convertible to bool: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if . Without the else, it could be `for(PosCp * p = dynamic_cast<PosCp *>(Cps["Pos"].get()); p; p = nullptr){ ... }`